# Fourier transform of image in magnitude not working

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

I want to plot magnitude and phase of the Fourier transform of an image in matlab. I implemented the tutorial I read in this [link](http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/how-to-do-a-2-d-fourier-transform-in-matlab/) line by line but for magnitude, only a white screen is plotted.

My code:

```
I=imread('16.jpg');
fftA = fft2(double(I));
figure, imshow(abs(fftshift(fftA)));
title('Image FFT2 Magnitude');
figure, imshow(angle(fftshift(fftA)),[-pi pi]);
title('Image   FFT2 Phase')
```

My original image is :
[image]

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things here.

1. Input image for 2D FFT should be intensity image (or grayscale), which is mxnx1 in size, not RGB, which is mxnx3 in size.
2. If image matrix is of class `double`, its intensity is expected to be in [0,1] range. Values greater than 1 will be shown as 1 (filled with highest color of figure colormap).

To convert RGB image to grayscale use `rgb2gray`:

```
Irgb  = imread('16.jpg');
Igray = rgb2gray(Irgb);
```

To solve latter rescale your image or use `imagesc` combined with `axis equal` to preserve scale:

```
figure;
imagesc(abs(fftshift(fftA))); axis equal; axis tight;
```